# Xpath compile Regex not showing xml comments

Tags: java, regex, xml, xpath, xml-parsing

Hey all I am terrible at Regex stuff and wondering what this *//*[not(*)] means exactly when placed into an XML XPath compile? Only thing I can find is (https://regex101.com/r/Kjodlj/1)

> Match a single character [not(*)].
>
> not(*) matches a single character not(*) (case sensitive)

```
NodeList nodeList = (NodeList) xPath.compile("//*[not(*)]").evaluate(document, XPathConstants.NODESET);
```

The above code does not seem to give me any of the comments that are throughout my XML file. Doing something like this:

```
NodeList nodeList = (NodeList) xPath.compile("//*").evaluate(document, XPathConstants.NODESET);
```

Does show the comments but also messes up the page parsing.

Is there a Regex that does both so that it still formats it correctly  and also includes the comments as well? Or perhaps doing this in another form that's easier than using regex?

Comment: Can you post a sample of your xml file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`XPath.compile` compiles XPath expressions, not Regex expressions. They are quite unrelated.

The XPath expression `//*[not(*)]` selects all elements in the document that do not have a child element (that is, all leaf elements). The way it works is:

1. `//` expands to `/descendant-or-self::node()/`
2. `*` expands to `child::element()`
3. `not(X)`, where `X` is a node-set, tests whether the node-set is empty.

So the expression means

```
/descendant-or-self::node()/child::element()[empty(child::element())]
```

Which selects all elements that are a child of something in the document (actually, all elements are a child of something), and then filters this set to retain only those where `child::element()` returns nothing, that is, those that have no child elements.

But first you need to get it out of your head that this has anything to do with regular expressions. If you search a Regex tutorial hoping to get insights about XPath, you are going to get very confused.

Comment: Maybe today will be better than [yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59737146/290085) for understanding similar [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59737146/parsing-xml-getting-comments-and-date-values-only#comment105624717_59737146)  and [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59741299/290085) regarding the difference between RegEx and XPath.